# Java sum of salaries from .csv file

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

I am trying to sum up salaries for each type of job from .csv file and right now my output only shows  how much each person earns. I need to sum this earing and I don't have any idea how to write method which will sum up salaries for each job. Do you have any idea how could I change my code to get sum of earings?

```
package src;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Path path = Path.of("sample.csv");
       try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);) {
           lines.filter(line -> line.startsWith(" "))
                .map(line -> LineToPerson(line))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
       }
       catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   private static Person LineToPerson(String line) {
       String[] elements = line.split(";");
       String id = elements[0];
       String name = elements[1];
       String surname = elements[2];
       String job = elements[3];
       Double salary = Double.valueOf(elements[4].replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll(",", "."));
       Person p = new Person(id, name, surname, job, salary);
       return p;
   }
}
```

--------------------class Person----------------------------------

```
package src;

public class Person {

   private String id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String job;
   private double salary;

   public Person() {

   }
   public Person(String id, String name, String surname, String job, double salary) {
       this.id = id.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
       this.name = name.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
       this.surname = surname.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
       this.job = job.replaceAll("\"", "").replaceAll(" ", "");
       this.salary = salary;
   }
   public String getId() {
       return id;
   }
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }
   public String getSurname() {
       return surname;
   }
   public String getJob() {
       return job;
   }
   public double getSalary() {
       return salary;
   }
   public String toString() {
       if (job.equals("Teacher")) {
           return "Teacher salary = " + salary;
       } else if (job.equals("Janitor")) {
           return "Janitor salary = " + salary;
       } else return "";
   }
}
```

Comment: Replace `.forEach(System.out::println);` with `.mapToDouble(Person::getSalary).sum()`. And print the entire expression.

Comment: For your toString() method, you might just want to do return job + " salary = " + salary; That way you get rid of the if-statement.

Comment: @sear1234 You should probably address your comment to Johannes Kuhn so he will be notified.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn where should i put my print command?

Comment: `System.out.println(lines.filter(line -> line.startsWith(" "))
                       .map(line -> LineToPerson(line))
                       .mapToDouble(Person::getSalary).sum());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `job` as follows:

```
lines.filter(line -> line.startsWith(" "))
        .map(line -> LineToPerson(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getJob(),
                                Collectors.summingDouble(person -> person.getSalary())))
        .forEach((job,sumSalary) -> System.out.println(job + "\t" + sumSalary));
```

Replace

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);) {
   lines.filter(line -> line.startsWith(" "))
        .map(line -> LineToPerson(line))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

with

```
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);) {
    lines.filter(line -> line.startsWith(" "))
        .map(line -> LineToPerson(line))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(person -> person.getJob(),
                                Collectors.summingDouble(person -> person.getSalary())))
        .forEach((job,sumSalary) -> System.out.println(job + "\t" + sumSalary));
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me where exactly should I put this command?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show where to add this code.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to change it :(

Comment: If you edit your question and post a few lines of your CSV file, I'll update my answer with the complete code.